# Symfony 2 web app showing wrong icon on iOS homescreen

Tags: ios, iphone, symfony

I have a Symfony 2.8 application that we're trying to prep for the "Add to home" option in iOS Safari.

I've followed Apple's documentation here to create the proper links: https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html

They look something like this, just with the proper paths to the my icons.

```
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" href="touch-icon-iphone.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="152x152" href="touch-icon-ipad.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="180x180" href="touch-icon-iphone-retina.png">
<link rel="apple-touch-icon" sizes="167x167" href="touch-icon-ipad-retina.png">
```

That being said, when I hop on my iPhone and try to add the website to my homescreen, it gives me a Symfony logo instead of my company's logo.

[image: Symfony's logo that shows up on my iphone]

Any ideas about where that logo may be coming from, and how I can get the correct one to show up?

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ Try clearing your cache.

Comment: Good idea, but no luck. Thanks though.

Comment: Just thought I'd also mention that i tried clearing my cache on my phone, as well as several different iPhone emulators through Xcode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, with a combined effort with some coworkers, we figured this one out.

I think the application I'm working was started from one of the Symfony example projects, and had included the icon pictured above in the web directory of the project. I didn't put it there, so I didn't have a clue where it came from until a coworker spotted it.

The second issue was that the directory where my icons were stored weren't publicly available. I had put them in the /web/icons directory, but for some reason they were unavailable in that directory. Probably an .htaccess file issue, as there are no other routes that would interfere. We ended up just moving the files to another directory.

Once those 2 issues were out of the way it worked perfect.